# Entity Framework IQueryable Deferred for Big Object with many conditions LinqtoEntity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I'm attempting to refactor some painfully slow code in the repository layer of a large property management system.

There was a pattern followed by the original dev team where they did not understand the nature of deferred execution in regards to the IQueryable.

Here is a code sample:

```
public PropertyDTO GetPropertyByPropertyAuctionID(Guid propertyAuctionId)
{
    PropertyDTO property = null;

    var result =
        (
            from pa in databaseContext.PropertyAuction
            join a in databaseContext.Auction on pa.AuctionID equals a.AuctionID into suba
            from sa in suba.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join an in databaseContext.AuctionNotifications
            on sa.AuctionNotificationsID equals an.AuctionNotificationsID into suban
            from san in suban.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where pa.PropertyAuctionID == propertyAuctionId
            where pa.IsDeleted == null || !(bool)pa.IsDeleted
            select new
            {
                PropertyAuction = pa,
                AuctionNotifications = san
            }
        ).FirstOrDefault();

    if (result != null)
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        property = ConvertPropertyFromDatabase(result.PropertyAuction, result.AuctionNotifications);
        //end can be upwards of 10-12 seconds per record
        var end = DateTime.Now - start;
    }
    else
    {
        throw CustomException.NotFound;
    }

    return property;
}

internal PropertyDTO ConvertPropertyFromDatabase(PropertyAuction propertyAuction, AuctionNotifications auctionNotifications = null)
{
    Property property = null;

    PropertyDTO dtoProperty = new PropertyDTO()
    {
        PropertyAuctionID = propertyAuction.PropertyAuctionID
    };

    if (propertyAuction.PropertyID.HasValue)
    {
        dtoProperty.PropertyID = propertyAuction.PropertyID.Value;
        property = propertyAuction.Property;
        dtoProperty.IsSimulcastAuction = propertyAuction.IsSimulcastAuction;
        dtoProperty.IsSold = propertyAuction.IsSold;
        dtoProperty.PropertyExecutionInitialValue = propertyAuction.ExecutionInitialValue;
    }

    if (propertyAuction.User4 != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyAuction.User4.Profile1.FirstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyAuction.User4.Profile1.LastName))
    {
        dtoProperty.OfferAdministratorFirstName = propertyAuction.User4.Profile1.FirstName;
        dtoProperty.OfferAdministratorLastName = propertyAuction.User4.Profile1.LastName;
        dtoProperty.OfferAdministratorUserID = propertyAuction.OfferAdministratorUserID;
    }

    if (propertyAuction.AuctionID.HasValue)
    {
        dtoProperty.AuctionID = propertyAuction.AuctionID;

        string auctionStartDateString = String.Empty;

        if (propertyAuction.Auction != null)
        {
            if (propertyAuction.Auction.AuctionStartDate.HasValue)
            {
                auctionStartDateString = propertyAuction.Auction.AuctionStartDate.Value.Year + "-" + propertyAuction.Auction.AuctionStartDate.Value.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "-" + propertyAuction.Auction.AuctionStartDate.Value.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ": ";
            }
            dtoProperty.HMOnlineAuctionClosingStartDate = propertyAuction.Auction.AuctionClosingDate;

            dtoProperty.AuctionName = auctionStartDateString + propertyAuction.Auction.Title;
            dtoProperty.AuctionPublicSiteName = propertyAuction.Auction.PublicSiteName;
            dtoProperty.AuctionNumber = propertyAuction.Auction.AuctionNumber;
            dtoProperty.AuctionType = propertyAuction.Auction.AuctionType.Value;
            dtoProperty.OriginalAuctionID = propertyAuction.Auction.OriginalAuctionID;
            dtoProperty.AuctionTermsAndConditions = propertyAuction.Auction.TermsAndConditions;
            dtoProperty.BrochureFileName = propertyAuction.Auction.BrochureFileName;
            dtoProperty.BrochureName = propertyAuction.Auction.BrochureName;

            if (propertyAuction.Auction.LuJohnsAuctionDetails != null)
            {
                dtoProperty.LuJohnsAuctionLiveWebcastLink = propertyAuction.Auction.LuJohnsAuctionDetails.LiveWebcastLink;
            }
        }
    }

    if (propertyAuction.PropertyStatus != null)
    {
        dtoProperty.PropertyStatusID = propertyAuction.PropertyStatusID.Value;
        dtoProperty.PropertyStatusValue = propertyAuction.PropertyStatus.Value;
    }

    if (propertyAuction.PropertyAuctionAuctionDetails != null)
    {
        PropertyAuctionAuctionDetails propertyAuctionAuctionDetails = propertyAuction.PropertyAuctionAuctionDetails;
        dtoProperty.PropertyAuctionAuctionDetailsId = propertyAuction.PropertyAuctionAuctionDetailsID;
        SetShowOnWebsiteProperty(dtoProperty, propertyAuction);
        SetWebsiteButtonProperty(dtoProperty, propertyAuctionAuctionDetails, propertyAuctionAuctionDetails.PreSaleMethod,
            propertyAuctionAuctionDetails.AuctionMethod, propertyAuctionAuctionDetails.PostSaleMethod);
    }
//This goes on for an astounding 900 more lines of code
}
```

As you can probably guess, this is making significant repeat trips to the database.

What is the fastest way to refactor this code to make the fewest number of trips to the database?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that this `ConvertPropertyFromDatabase()` method triggers lots of queries for lazily loaded properties. I suggest you turn of lazy loading in you `DbContext` class like this:

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Then you have to check which properties are accessed in this convert method, and rewrite your query so these are explicitly loaded.